# jQuery ajax error code: what does "error" really mean?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've implemented ajax call using jQuery and in case of error, I could look for `textStatus` to determine whether the error is **"timeout", "error", "abort", "parseerror".**

But **what does "error" really stands for? 404(not found)? 408(timeout)?**

code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../resources/plan/get/" + planno,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, txtStat, xhr) {
            console.log("success:" + txtStat);
        },
        error: function(xhr, txtStat, errThrown) {
            if(txtStat === "timeout") { 
                console.log("ajax has timed-out! " + txtStat + ":::" + errThrown);
            }
            else if(txtStat === "error") {

              //so..what is error means???


            }
            //TODO write else..
        }
});
```

I wonder if it is everything other than HTTP 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess everything except 200. Can't you look at `xhr.status` to see what error code the server returned?

Comment: In case of error, xhr.status and xhr.readyState both returned 0

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry it wasn't case of error, it was case of "timeout".. I must change my server code to return like 500 to test this.

Comment: Ok... I changed server code to return 404, and xhr.status = 404 and xhr.readyState = 4 were returned. I think that would be the way to determine. Thanks for the insight.